# How to execute bash script without password?

Tags: linux, bash, archlinux

I need to execute the script after system boot. 
For example:

```
(sleep 5 && (sudo dhcpcd wlp4s0))
```

What I need: Executing the script.
What I have: [sudo] password for eugene: 
I has been edited /etc/sudoers so:

```
eugene ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/eugene/dhcpcdstart.sh
```

But it's ineffectually. How I can to execute the current script without password?
Arch Linux 2013.05.01

Comment: belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: Yes, and already answered there: [How to execute a shell script on startup?](http://superuser.com/questions/126106/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-on-startup)

Comment: @sleske Arch did'nt have /etc/init.d directory

Comment: First of all I think you didn't really said what you need. Do you want that script to be automatically executed after boot? Maybe you just want a dhcp interface configured on some linux distro (that you didn't mention) and you found a more complicated way to do it. And maybe that question should end up on superuser.com if you want an answer.

Comment: @Mihai In my topic one question only: "How I can to execute the current script without password?"

Comment: Use a systemd service file...

Comment: On superuser.com I have +4 reputation in the same question. And -2 here. LOL :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your sudoers configuration and it works (not with dhcpcd, since I don't have it). Just make sure that you put that line at the end of sudoers file containing dhcpcd in the file list (I guess your script has executing rights for eugene user, but dhcpcd doesn't).

eugene ALL=NOPASSWD: dhcpcd_path/dhcpcd

Comment: Yes, but I need to execute dhcpcd with "wlp4s0" argument.

Comment: @eugene: In that file you just specify that dhcpcd doesn't need password for execution with `sudo`. The arguments are not relevant.